# JAXB 2: unmarshalling xml without xml declaration

Tags: java, xml-parsing, jaxb2

Good time!

I have an xml:

```
<fieldSet name="Test" desc="Test">
  <field name="id">
    <fieldinfo>
        <name>id</name>
        <type>String</type>
        <fieldsize>50</fieldsize>
    </fieldinfo>
    <validators />
  </field>
</fieldSet>
```

and I need to parse it using JAXB. I've tried this:

```
        try {
            JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(CustomFieldSet.class);
            Unmarshaller unmarshaller = jaxbContext.createUnmarshaller();

            StringReader reader = new StringReader(xml);
            CustomFieldSet fieldSet = (CustomFieldSet) unmarshaller.unmarshal(reader);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            logger.error(e.getMessage(), e); 
        }
```

where the CustomFieldSet class starts with:

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlRootElement(name = "fieldSet")
public class CustomFieldSet {

@XmlAttribute(name = "name", required = true)
private String tableName;

@XmlAttribute(name = "desc", required = true)
private String tableDescription;

    ...
```

When the unmarshal() function is called the following exception is thrown:

```
javax.xml.bind.UnmarshalException - with linked exception: [org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: Content is not allowed in prolog.]
```

I think the problem is connected with the fact my xml doesn't contain an xml declaration (`<?xml ...`).

Does anybody know what is the workaround here?

Comment: That code works for me. Are you sure there isn't some other problem with your XML?

Comment: I tried your sample with file and this exception was thrown in case of non-accessible file. Are you sure variable xml contains the xml provided? Btw. You have typo in: talbeDescription (maybe you wanted tableDescription)

Comment: @artbristol, I've also thought there are some problems with xml, so that I've tried: XMLInputFactory xif = XMLInputFactory.newFactory();
    StreamSource xml = new StreamSource(new StringReader(tableDescription));
    XMLStreamReader xsr = xif.createXMLStreamReader(xml);
    xsr.nextTag();

    JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(CustomFieldSet.class);
    Unmarshaller unmarshaller = jaxbContext.createUnmarshaller();

    JAXBElement<CustomFieldSet> jb = unmarshaller.unmarshal(xsr, CustomFieldSet.class);

Comment: and an error raised: "javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamException: ParseError at [row,col]:[1,1]
Message: Content is not allowed in prolog."

Comment: @Peter Butkovic, thank you, this is a typo =) Yes, I've run this in a debug mode and the xml string does contain the xml

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[**JAXB (JSR-222)**](http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=222) implementations do not require the XML header (i.e. `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>`), see below for an example.  I suspect the there is something special about the XML string in your example.

**Java Model (Foo)**

```
package forum13341366;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.*;

@XmlRootElement
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Foo {

    private String bar;

}
```

**Demo Code**

```
package forum13341366;

import java.io.StringReader;
import javax.xml.bind.*;

public class Demo {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(Foo.class);

        Unmarshaller unmarshaller = jc.createUnmarshaller();
        StringReader xml = new StringReader("<foo><bar>Hello World</bar></foo>");
        Foo foo = (Foo) unmarshaller.unmarshal(xml);

        Marshaller marshaller = jc.createMarshaller();
        marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);
        marshaller.marshal(foo, System.out);
    }

}
```

**Output**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<foo>
    <bar>Hello World</bar>
</foo>
```

---

Answer (score 3):

I've changed the code to work with InputStream instead of the StringReader and now everything works:

```
try {
            XMLInputFactory xif = XMLInputFactory.newFactory();
            InputStream bis = new ByteArrayInputStream(tableDescription.getBytes("UTF-8"));
            XMLStreamReader xsr = xif.createXMLStreamReader(bis, "UTF-8");

            xsr.nextTag();

            JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(CustomFieldSet.class);
            Unmarshaller unmarshaller = jaxbContext.createUnmarshaller();

            JAXBElement<CustomFieldSet> jb = unmarshaller.unmarshal(xsr, CustomFieldSet.class);
            xsr.close();

            fieldSet = jb.getValue();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            logger.error(e.getMessage(), e);
        }
```